# table valued function python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, table-functions

How to call table value function in python ?

Tried

In [73]: cur.callproc('fn_',('blah','12/31/2013','9/13/2014')) but doesn't work

Error:

MSSQLDatabaseException: (2809, "The request for procedure 'fn_' failed because 'fn_' is a table valued function object.DB-Lib error message 2809, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error
: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")